# Odoo 16 restoring 350 MB database Ubuntu Nginx

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

### **What I am trying:**

I am trying to restore Odoo 16 enterprise database with size `350MBs` and I am using Digitaloceans and Nginx as a proxy.

### **Error I am getting:**

```
Error Code: 413
Request Entity Too Large
The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.
```

### **What I have tried:**

I have edited nginx `odoo.conf` file and nginx.conf file with the following:

```
client_max_body_size 900M;
client_body_timeout 1300;
proxy_read_timeout 1300;
```

I have restarted nginx and odoo service multiple time.
I have increased Postgres resources.

But same issue.

Comment: I think this got migrated by mistake. The only connection to DBA SE is "restore", and you didn't describe the procedure at all.

Comment: Why not use pg_dump and pg_restore?